# iterate over bigrams(tuple) given by nltk : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable, Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, nltk

I just started working with nltk and python, and I am having a small problem while iterating over the list of bigrams returned by nltk.

Example of what I want:

this is the list of bigrams:
[('more', 'is'), ('is', 'said'), ('said', 'than'), ('than', 'done')]

What I want is to be able to get each bigram : (more,is) and each term of each bigram:more, is etc separately

Here is what I tried so far, based on some answers in stackoverflow:

```
bigrams = nltk.bigrams(doclist)

#method 1   
for (a, b) in bigrams: #I get this error:  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
    print a 
    print b 

#method 2
#convert to a list first 
bigrams = list(bigrams)# I get the same error
for (a, b) in bigrams:
    print a 
    print b

#method 3
#convert to a dict first
dct = dict(tuples)# I get the same error
```

I assume that this bigrams are a list of tuples, so what am I doing wrong?

Can you please point me out to any working code or tutorial. I will also be happy to accept any correct answer.

Thank you in advance

Note: I am working with python 2.7

Comment: Your first attempt works for me: `for (a, b) in bigrams:`

If `bigrams` was None at this point, that would explain the error you got.

Comment: Yes how stupid is that ! I've forgotten the return statement in the the function I was using so the bigrams were None. Thanks for your observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for iterating inside a tuple you need just use variables (with the number of `bigram` indexes ) not tuple like this:(`for (a, b) in bigrams`) , and  if you just want each `bigram` use `ONE variable` in your loop  :

for better understanding see the below Demo :

```
>>> bigrams=[('more', 'is'), ('is', 'said'), ('said', 'than'), ('than', 'done')]
>>> for a, b in bigrams: 
...     print a 
...     print b 
... 
more
is
is
said
said
than
than
done
>>> for a in bigrams:
...  print a
... 
('more', 'is')
('is', 'said')
('said', 'than')
('than', 'done')
>>>
```